# Add email address to outlook distribution list

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have a distribution list under "Global Address List". I want to read the members of that group and add new members to the same distribution list. Is there anyway to do that in python using win32com?

I am able to read members of the distribution list. Need help with adding addresses to distribution list

## python

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
address_lists = ns.AddressLists.Item('Global Address List')
contacts = address_lists.AddressEntries.Item(MyGroup).Members
group_mail_list = []
for c in contacts:
       group_mail_list.append(c.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to modify GAL from the client side. It has to be done from the Exchange Admin Console.